# I can't usa Obx to update my state page. How can i?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I have this error "      [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx
or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
(example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
"

I have this page

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/application/themes/theme_config.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/modules/home/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/modules/home/widget/components/page_two_components.dart/search_bar.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/modules/home/widget/components/page_two_components.dart/search_custom_delegate.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/modules/home/widget/components/page_two_components.dart/section.dart';

class PageTwo extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const PageTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                title: Text(
                  "Buscar",
                  style: ThemeConfig().getTextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
              )
            ];
          },
          body: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => showSearch(
                  context: context,
                  delegate: SearchCustomDelegate(),
                ),
                child: const SearchBar(),
              ),
              Obx(() => Section(
                    title: "Navegar por todas seções",
                    items: controller.allSections,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside controller i declared "allSections" like:
 `RxList<SectionItemModel> allSections = <SectionItemModel>[].obs;`

Answer (score 1):

**Obx()** is used only when there is an extended class of ***GetxController*** inside.
I can only see *HomeController*. But I can't see where you initialized *controller* inside ***PageTwo***.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/application/themes/theme_config.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/modules/home/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/modules/home/widget/components/page_two_components.dart/search_bar.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/modules/home/widget/components/page_two_components.dart/search_custom_delegate.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/modules/home/widget/components/page_two_components.dart/section.dart';

class PageTwo extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const PageTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text(
                    "Buscar",
                    style: ThemeConfig().getTextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                )
              ];
            },
            body: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => showSearch(
                    context: context,
                    delegate: SearchCustomDelegate(),
                  ),
                  child: const SearchBar(),
                ),
                Obx(() => Section(
                  title: "Navegar por todas seções",
                  items: controller.allSections,
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
Inside controller i declared "allSectio
```